# How to setup rasa multilingual bot on local system

Tags: python, docker, heroku, rasa

I have gone through rasa multilingual demobot: https://rasa.com/showcase/multilingual-demobot

I got the concept of rasa bot, but as I don’t have any knowledge on docker and Heroku I am not able to run the bot on my local system.

can anyone tell me how can I achieve it,? probably without Heroku and docker

Comment: You can look into the Dockerfile to see how to set up the bot locally. It pretty much lists the steps you need to make to install the dependencies. Furthermore I recommend you to go with the Docker route since it is easier and the chance of you breaking your system is lessened. Try to get the bot running via Docker and come back when you are stuck at specific steps. There are plenty of guides on how to use Docker and if you can't follow them us explaining it to you won't get us further. You explaining where exactly you are stuck is more helpful.

Comment: in dockerfile its only installing requirement that i have installed already, my question is the way we run a rasa bot locally with "rasa shell" and "rasa run actions". 
how can i run the 2 bots ( en and de) locally?